# Adding UIScrollView in a UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitabbarcontroller

I have a current project set up like the picture below, and I am trying to insert a scrollView inside one of the navigation controllers which is inside a tab bar controller. However, when I click on the TabBar icon associated with the "moreTableViewController," I get a blank screen. I do have a MoreTableViewController.xib set up with a bunch of labels to see whether I can get it to show up or get the scrollView to work. But nothing is being displayed.

Not sure how to implement the scrollView properly. Any tips will be appreciated.

Thanks.

[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you've specified the nib name in the inspector, as illustrated:

[image]

In MoreTableViewController.xib, add a `UIScrollView` into the view hierarchy, and connect it to an appropriate IBOutlet on your view controller, as shown here:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have added the scrollView and it is now scrolling. However, the top of the viewController is being hidden behind the navigation bar. As you can see in the picture below, the view is going over navigation bar. And I cannot seem to find a way to resize the view inside the tabBarController.
[link](http://i.imgur.com/ppqhPBR.png)

Comment: I had no issues when I put simulated nav bar / status bar / tab bars in my MoreTableViewController.xib - are you doing that?

Comment: I believe I am doing that. This is what my .xib file looks like, [link](http://i.imgur.com/QowYy6i.png). And this is what is showing up on the simulator, [link](http://i.imgur.com/kEO3Xb5.png). There is one more item that is suppose to be on the simulator, but it is hidden behind the navigation bar and only shows up when you drag the screen down, after dragging the screen down, it bounces back to the original position.

Comment: Something is likely misconfigured in your xibs, but your screen shots don't show enough details. This is quite a different issue than your original question so it's probably best to ask a new one.

Comment: I actually got it to work. I had to enable "auto layout" in the .xibs. Thank you for all your help. I really appreciate it.